# How can I change this Boolean expression returning undefined instead false?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am not so into JavaScript\TypeScript and I am finding the following problem with this code:

```
let timeStampAsDate = new Date();
let term = "2021";

console.log("XXX: ", timeStampAsDate?.getFullYear().toString().toLowerCase().includes(term) && timeStampAsDate != null);

let timeStampAsDate2 = undefined;

console.log("XXX: ", timeStampAsDate2?.getFullYear().toString().toLowerCase().includes(term) && timeStampAsDate2 != null);
```

[Here you can run the code and see the output](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBGCWC2IGUwENYAcCCBnAIssIEAvBAHYgDuEeBAFAJQDcAUKJAQE6zEQBEATAAZ+ARl4tmAYwD2pLNNAA6YNIDmtXgA1tALj4AaKHEQp02GiAD8i1eABiAV2DAAmiGQcGisNKQdopOr03tIAMtIUIBwAwshYIF4BksAOACYgWLScsPQQAGR5RvBIqJi4+IQAhCSkTsBMzKzgRSal5hX8PA6k6QBmASCpEjJyCiDKahramnq8hjDFpmUW-Na2YI7Obh5ePn4BQSHhkTFxCcFJKemZ2bkFLSVm5QSd1WR1DY3MEBBAA)

I'll try to explain what is my problem:

As you can see in the previous code I have 2 different use cases, in the first one I first create a `Date` object and then I have a `term` representing an year that will be later used in a search (basically I am searching the inserted term representing a year into the year field of my date):

```
let timeStampAsDate = new Date();
let term = "2021";

console.log("XXX: ", timeStampAsDate?.getFullYear().toString().toLowerCase().includes(term) && timeStampAsDate != null);
```

If it is retrieved it print the Boolean value true. It works fine.

The second case is related to the use case where I have no date (this because in my application I can have undefined field of this type, because these data came from a Firebase database and can be not present):

```
let timeStampAsDate2 = undefined;

console.log("XXX: ", timeStampAsDate2?.getFullYear().toString().toLowerCase().includes(term) && timeStampAsDate2 != null);
```

Here I am not obtaining a Boolean value but in my console I am obtaining this output:

```
    XXX:  undefined
```

My idea is that having this `&& timeStampAsDate2 != null` into my confition the final value have to be false but I discovered that in JavaScript\TypeScript an expression like this:

```
console.log(undefined && false)
```

give undefined as result and not false.

What can be a nice way to change my original condition in such a way that it is evaluated as false and not as undefined in the case that my `timeStampAsDate2` is undefined?

Comment: Why would you lowercase an int?

Comment: You can use the ["bang, bang you're boolean" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript#comment11728310_784929).

Answer (score 1):

Why the string handling, just compare ints

We can add the !! to force a boolean on the undefined variable

```js
let timeStampAsDate = new Date(2021,05,14,15,0,0,0); // today, to not make this weird next year
let term = 2021; // INT

console.log("XXX: ", !!timeStampAsDate && timeStampAsDate?.getFullYear() === term )

let timeStampAsDate2;

console.log("XXX: ", !!timeStampAsDate2 && timeStampAsDate?.getFullYear() === term )

// my code with the nullish coalescing operator is still much shorter

let timeStampAsDate3;

console.log("XXX: ",  timeStampAsDate3?.getFullYear() === term  ?? false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator): (??) may be what you are after. It works really well with optional chaining. If the value is undefined it returns a default value.

```
let timeStampAsDate2 = undefined;
let term = "2021";
console.log("XXX: ", timeStampAsDate2?.getFullYear().toString().toLowerCase().includes(term) ?? false)
```

Comment: Still: Why string and tolowercase.

Comment: True @mplungjan! Love your recap! My main goal was to share about the Nullish Coalescing Operator for this specific issue. I wanted to leave the code as is as much as possible. Agreed, the toLowerCase is unnecessary. The toString may be helpful if the feature is to allow a user to type in a partial number (such as: 202 and get back 2020 or 2021). Unlikely but in any scenario, the solutions you summarized will be a good starting point!

Comment: Also @mplungjan I cannot comment yet on your answer yet but one to add! If term is guaranteed (at least an empty string "") then `console.log("XXX: ",  timeStampAsDate3?.getFullYear() === term)` should work too, as undefined will not equal a string.